# RxJS Observables: Creating with values

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I don't yet have the service to call for the values, so I am doing some boiler plate code with aysnc ngFors.

I am trying to create an obserable that can be consumed by an ngFor. I try:

```
 statuses$ = Observable.create((o) => {
    o.next(new NameValue('Open', 'OPEN'));
    o.next(new NameValue('Closed', 'CLOSED'));
    o.complete();
  });
```

then

```
        <mat-option *ngFor="let status of statuses$ | async" [value]="status.value">
          {{ status.name }}
        </mat-option>
```

but I get an Async error

Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Open'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: `subscribe` returns `Subscription` object, not observable.

Comment: Why are you subscribing *and* using an async pipe?

Comment: mistakenly added subscribe, but it still fails. hmmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulate your observable like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';    

statuses$ = of([new NameValue('Open', 'OPEN'), new NameValue('Closed', 'CLOSED')]);
```

which gives an array that `*ngFor` can interpret, rather than the object you are returning currently.